# May be a bug? Where can I find the meaning of parameter in docplex?

Tags: cplex, docplex

when I want to search the meaning of parameter value in docplex, it seems to go wrong. The following is the code:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
import cplex
model_do = Model()


# the following two lines work well
''' 
the output of first line:
  'method for linear optimization:\n  0 = automatic\n  1 = primal simplex\n  2 = dual simplex\n  3 = network simplex\n  4 = barrier\n  5 = sifting\n  6 = concurrent optimizers'
the output of second line:
  class NumParameter(Parameter)
     |  NumParameter(env, about, parent, name, constants=None)
     ...
'''
cplex.Cplex().parameters.lpmethod.help()
help(cplex.Cplex().parameters.lpmethod)


# however, when it comes docplex, sth goes wrong
''' 
the output of first line:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'IntParameter' object has no attribute 'help'
the output of second line:
  class IntParameter(Parameter)
   |  IntParameter(group, short_name, cpx_name, param_key, description, default_value, min_value=None, max_value=None, sync=False)
   ...
'''
model_do.parameters.lpmethod.help()
help(model_do.parameters.lpmethod)
```

**my question** are:

1.the parameters values' meanings in docplex are truly the same as in cplex?

2.If the answer of question.1 is "no", where can I search for the parameters values' meanings in docplex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the description field.
Let me change the [example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoosettings.py) from [easy optimization with python](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/) to show this:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')

mdl.parameters.timelimit=20;
mdl.set_time_limit(20) #The same


print("number_of_params = ",mdl.parameters.number_of_params)
for i in mdl.parameters.iter_params():
    print(i)
    print(i.description)

nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

mdl.export("c:\\temp\\buses.lp")

print("time limit = ",mdl.parameters.timelimit.get())
print("time limit = ",mdl.get_time_limit()) #The same

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

gives

```
number_of_params =  15
advance:int(1)
indicator for advanced starting information
clocktype:int(2)
type of clock used to measure time
dettimelimit:number(1e+75)
deterministic time limit in ticks
lpmethod:int(0)
method for linear optimization
optimalitytarget:int(0)
type of solution CPLEX will attempt to compute
parallel:int(0)
parallel optimization mode
paramdisplay:bool(1)
whether to display changed parameters before optimization
qpmethod:int(0)
method for quadratic optimization
randomseed:int(202009243)
seed to initialize the random number generator
record:bool(0)
record calls to C API
solutiontype:int(0)
solution information CPLEX will attempt to compute
threads:int(0)
default parallel thread count
timelimit:number(20.0)
time limit in seconds
workdir:string('.')
directory for CPLEX working files
workmem:number(2048.0)
memory available for working storage (in megabytes)
time limit =  20.0
time limit =  20.0
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0
```

Comment: By the way, how can I get the meaning of a parameter when its' value is specific? The method you gave above seems not to tell that 0 denotes automatic choice of the algorithm( "lpmethod:int(0)" for example). So, if I want to look up things like this, what can I do?

Comment: Hi, you could simply have a look at online documentation https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.0?topic=cplex-list-parameters